# Enable submit button only when there are characters in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea

I'm working on a basic form that has one textarea and one submit button:

```
<form action="admin-post.php" method="post">

    <textarea style="width:630px;" aria-hidden="true" class="wp-editor-area" rows="6" autocomplete="off" cols="71" name="author_message" id="author_message"></textarea>

    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Post Message" class="button button-primary" id="submit" name="submit">
    </p>

</form>
```

I want the submit button to be enabled only if there is some text entered within the textarea. How can I do this using Javascript?

Note that I cannot change the the value or HTML code of the submit button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need continuous verification solve it like this (without changing the button attributes):

```
<textarea style="width:630px;" aria-hidden="true" class="wp-editor-area" rows="6" autocomplete="off" cols="71" name="author_message" id="author_message" onkeyup="if(this.textLength != 0) {submit.disabled = false} else {submit.disabled = true}"></textarea>
```

and modify the body tag:

```
<body onload="submit.disabled = true">
```

Cheers

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tv1sp4d/2/)

**edit:**

If you cannot modify the body tag, just add the disabled attribute to the button.

Comment: I can't make this work. Can you please show me a working example using JSFiddle? Note that I cannot adjust the body tag of the page, however, I can add "disabled" to the submit button, and all Javascript must be inserted inside the body tag. So just above the form.

Comment: My code demonstrates a solution with the javascript inside the body tag. (textarea "author_message" is placed in the body section) Did you mean between the body- and the form-tag?

Comment: Works great. I have one final question. What about browser compatibility? Will this work on most browsers?

Comment: It should! I tested it with both FireFox and Chrome. Microsoft IE is always a bit stupid in handling code, it also depends on the version. If it doesn't work properly, try adding `disabled="disabled"` instead of just adding `disabled`.

Answer (score 2):

Working code here [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/lasoj/5/edit) :) i used `HTML` `Disable` attribute

Comment: As I noted in my question, I cannot alter the HTML of the Submit button. Do you have a different approach when this is still possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the submit button in the DOM first and disable it and then attach an event listener to the textarea, wherein you disable/enable the submit button based on whether the textarea is empty or not:

```
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("author_message").addEventListener('change', func, false);

function func(){
 document.getElementById("submit").disabled =  (document.getElementById("author_message").value==='') ;
}
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/11wsx5by/).